# Тормозит простая 2D игра

Tags: java, swing, графика, разработка-игр, 2d

Обучаюсь Java, сейчас пытался просто ради интереса написать такую простую 2D игру: управляем в пределах окна при помощи мышки красным кругом, уворачиваясь от бесконечно летящих сверху черных треугольников. Застрял на этапе добавления треугольников: fps падает до 5-3, когда треугольников около 20-25 (есть скрин). Так как треугольников бесконечное множество, запихиваю их, их координаты в четыре `ArrayList` (понадобилось именно 4), добавляются по 1 каждую секунду. Вопрос: почему же лаги и как увеличить количество памяти, выделяемое для программы, чтобы треугольники при нормальном fps хотя бы до нижнего края долетали? Что в данном случае можно сделать для оптимизации?

До появления треугольников(97-100fps):

[image]

После(10 fps):

[image]

Вот так выглядит кусок кода, отвечающий за fps:

```
public void run() {
    gc.setActionTime(true);
    long last1 = System.currentTimeMillis(),last2 = System.currentTimeMillis(),lastaction = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(r){
        long delta1 = System.currentTimeMillis()-last1;
        long delta2 = System.currentTimeMillis()-last2;
        long deltaaction = System.currentTimeMillis()-lastaction;
        if(delta1>=1000D/100D){
            last1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            gc.render();
            gc.tick();
            fps++;
        }
        if(delta2>=1000){
            f.setTitle(fps+"fps");
            fps=0;
            last2=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        if(deltaaction>=1000){
            lastaction = System.currentTimeMillis();
            gc.setActionTime(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит основной код(не полностью):

```
public class GameContent {

    Canvas c;
    JOptionPane j;
    int W, H;
    int ticks = 0;
    ArrayList < Obstacle > o = new ArrayList < Obstacle > (1);
    ArrayList < Integer > o_x = new ArrayList < Integer > (1);
    ArrayList < Integer > o_y = new ArrayList < Integer > (1);
    ArrayList < Integer > yOffsets = new ArrayList < Integer > (1);
    Random r;
    Graphics2D g;
    boolean clicked = false, actiontime = false, started = false;
    Player p;
    int x, y, x_o;

    public GameContent(Canvas c) {
        this.c = c;
        x = c.getWidth() / 2 - 25;
        y = c.getHeight() - 70;
        W = c.getWidth();
        H = c.getHeight();
        p = new Player();
        r = new Random();


        c.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            int x1 = x;
            int y1 = y;

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == e.getComponent()) if (!clicked) {
                    clicked = true;
                    started = true;
                } {
                    x = e.getX() - 10;
                    y = e.getY() - 10;
                }

            }


            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }

        });
    }

    public synchronized void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = c.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            c.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

        g.drawImage(p.getImage(), x, y, null);
        if (clicked) {
            for (int i = 0; i < o.size(); i++) {
                g.drawImage(o.get(i).getImage(), o_x.get(i), o_y.get(i) + yOffsets.get(i), null);
            }
        }

        if (actiontime) {
            actiontime = false;
            o.add(new Obstacle());
            o_x.add(r.nextInt(c.getWidth()));
            o_y.add(10);
            yOffsets.add(0);
        }


        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }
```

Comment: Олежка, к сожалению, все штатные экстрасенсы Stack Overflow на русском сейчас в отпуске. Для того, чтобы вам смогли помочь простые смертные, добавьте в вопрос ваш код.

Comment: Добавил то, что значимо

Comment: Покажите реализацию класса Obstacle - вожможно, там используется Image вместо BufferedImage или выполняются какие-то расчёты в методе getImage. Ещё пара советов: 1) не надо хранить координаты в отдельном массиве, их можно поместить в экземпляры класса Obstacle 2) в методе run() не  надо постоянно вызывать System.getCurrentMillis(), лучше сохранять время в переменную, тогда достаточно получать время один раз до цикла и один раз внутри цикла.